# Can i use one calculated field to "Computed column Specification" for other field calculation?

Tags: sql-server

I have two Child tables 1. Borrower list, 2. Return list.

i have following fields in  Return list table :

```
1.RETURNLISTID-->PKEY
2.MEMBERSHIPID -->FKEY
3.BOOKREFID--FKEY
4.MEMBERFULLNAME-->CALCULATED FIELD(FOR THE CORRESPONDING MEMBERSHIPID GET    VALUE FROM MEMBERS TABLE)
5.BORROWDATE-->CALCULATED FIELD(FOR THE CORRESPONDING MEMBERSHIPID,BOOKREFID GET VALUE FROM BORROWERLIST TABLE)
6.ACTUALRETURNDATE--> CALCULATED FIELD(FOR THE CORRESPONDING MEMBERSHIPID,BOOKREFID GET VALUE FROM BORROWERLIST TABLE)
7.USERRETURNDATE-->USER WILL ENTER
8.FINEAMT-->IT SHOULD BE A CALCULATED FIELD.I HAVE CREATED A FUNCTION.
```

i have created one function to calculate fineamt using ACTUALRETURNDATE AND USERRETURNDATE. I AM GETTING ERROR WHEN I CALL MY FUNCTION IN THE FIELD.

SO,My doubt is can i use one calculated field to function ?

find my function below.

```
create function dbo.GETFINEAMT(@ACTUALRETURNDATE DATETIME ,@USERRETURNDATE    DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @FINEAMT INT
DECLARE @DATEDIFF INT
SET @DATEDIFF=CONVERT(INT,(DATEDIFF(DD,'@ACTUALRETURNDATE','@USERRETURNDATE')))
SET @DATEDIFF = ABS(@DATEDIFF)
SET @FINEAMT=@DATEDIFF *10
RETURN @FINEAMT
END
GO
```

Comment: Insert Your resultset to a #table then pass it to the function

Comment: Can you add create scripts of table and function?

Comment: I dropped that fineamt column and added again using the query ALTER TABLE RETURNLIST ADD FINEAMT AS dbo.GETFINEAMT(ACTUALRETURNDATE,USERRETURNDATE). but still i am getting that error. "Computed column 'ACTUALRETURNDATE' in table 'RETURNLIST' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition."

Comment: Added my function above.

Comment: ACTUALRETURNDATE COLUMN IS COMPUTED COLUMN.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.There are so many computed field in single table.BTW,ACTUALRETURNDATE and FINEAMT cannot be computed column in same table .Firstly your table design and requirement is not clear.So many thing come to my mind .In nuthshell remove all computed column and place all business logic in Trigger .But for very accurate solution,the whole thing should be very clear.

Answer (score 0):

if all computed columns value are coming from UDF then you must be making mistake somewhere.So will hv to see your code.

See this straight exmple throw error,

```
Declare @t table(col int,col2 as col+1 PERSISTED,col3 as col2+1)
insert into @t values(1)
select * from @t
```

Comment: I dropped that fineamt column and added again using the query ALTER TABLE RETURNLIST ADD FINEAMT AS dbo.GETFINEAMT(ACTUALRETURNDATE,USERRETURNDATE). but still i am getting that error. "Computed column 'ACTUALRETURNDATE' in table 'RETURNLIST' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition."

Comment: Added my function above.

Comment: ACTUALRETURNDATE COLUMN IS COMPUTED COLUMN.